# Excel Interop: Filtering a Sorted Range/Worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, excel-interop, autofilter

I am despairing with a seemingly simple task in an Excel add-in written in C# using Excel Interop. I have a sheet with a table in it, and want to sort **and** filter the table:

```
Worksheet mainSheet = workbook.Worksheets["Master"];

int lastRow = ExcelUtils.getLastRow(mainSheet);
Range mainTableRange = mainSheet.Range["A1:G" + lastRow];

// disable AutoFilter
if (mainSheet.AutoFilter != null && mainSheet.AutoFilterMode == true)
{ 
    mainSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData();
    mainSheet.AutoFilterMode = false;
}

// remove any sorting
mainSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear();
masterSheet.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear();

// filter
mainTableRange.AutoFilter(Field: 3, Criteria1: "P01");
mainTableRange.AutoFilter(Field: 4, Criteria1: 1);

// sort
mainSheet.AutoFilter.Sort.Header = XlYesNoGuess.xlYes;
mainSheet.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add(masterTableRange.Columns[1], SortOn: XlSortOn.xlSortOnValues, Order: XlYesNoGuess.xlYes);
```

This when the table is not sorted already, i.e. if it runs for the first time. If I manually sort the table before the first run, or if it is run twice, the AutoFilter fails. The error message is in German, but it's something along the lines that the "_AutoFilter method of the range object could not be executed" with the generic 0x800A03EC exception.

Does anybody know how to sort **and** filter a table with Excel Interop?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

e_dude

[PS rant: The Interop is killing me! not only is the structure confusing (there is Worksheet.Sort, Worksheet.Autofilter.Sort, and Range.Sort, all of which are subtly different), but the documentation is abysmal. The nuances of the different sort methods are not explained, limitations of the AutoFilter on sorted ranges are not mentioned, examples are sparse. It is a real pain in the behind to work with this thing! ]

Comment: There is a total mess in the code you've provided - you're telling, that you have one sheet and one table, but there are two sheets (mainSheet and masterSheet) and two tables (mainTableRange and masterTableRange) in the code provied which are messed between each other.

Comment: What I see from your code, is the following sequence:
1 Main sheet declaration (mainSheet)
2 Finding last row (int lastRow)
3 Declaring main table (Range mainTableRange)
4 Disabling autofilter at the mainSheet (if {...})
5 Remove sorting from mainSheet (.Sort.SortFields.Clear();)
6 Removing sorting from unknown "Master sheet" (masterSheet)
7 Adding two filters to main table range (mainTable.AutoFilter)
8 Specifying that the first row of main sheet contains header information (.Sort.Header = ...)
9 Creating a new sort field with a key refering to unknown "masterTableRange"